# Automized opening of each search results (element data-ihref)

Tags: python, selenium, search, web-scraping, href

I am pretty new in Webscraping with Selenium. At the moment, I have created a Scraping tool, which opens a website with search results in a trading platform for trucks, which is printing information like price and age (year).
Unfortunately, the data base is not much in detail. For instance, I would like to get the age of those trucks as well in Month,Year. So, my aim is now, that the tool is not just printing the information from the search result pages, it should be also able to click inside each result to get more detailed information.

A way to get to the detailed page for a certain result is to click on the title which includes a:

*<div data-ihref="/daf-sattelzugmaschine-standard-xf-460/4x2-euro-6-niedersachsen/ts-vi5575257/gebrauchte.html"*

Each element is unique(title name), so I actually don't know how to deal with it. Happy to hear from you guys!

Right now, it looks like that:

````
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

#def get_truck_data(browser):
    # get all elements
    names = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('font-14.bold.h3')
    prices = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('row.infos.listing-price')
    tags = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('label-secondary')
    details = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('row.infos2.hidden-gallery')

    truck_list = []
    # Loop over elements
    for i in range(0, len(names)):
        name = names[i].text
        price = prices[i].text
        tag1, tag2 = tags[i].text, tags[i+1].text
        detail = details[i].text
        truck_list.append([name, price, tag1, tag2, detail])
    return truck_list

# Start Browser
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/dennisklingbeil/Downloads/chromedriver 5")

# Start Page
page = 1

 Main DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame()

# all pages
for i in range(0, 283):
    # open Europa LKW
    url = f"https://www.europa-lkw.de/sattelzugmaschinen-standard/diesel-ohne-kran/~a1b31c68k0q3/diesel-ohne-kran.html?crn=0&cvf=400&multi_euro=5-6&p={page}"
    driver.get(url)
    # Get Data
    single_list = get_truck_data(driver)

    df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(single_list))

    # Increase page counter
    page += 1
    time.sleep(2)

df = df.drop_duplicates()

df.to_excel('2020_08_20_Lkw_Europa.xlsx')```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find all enclosing `div` with classes `row-listing  page-break-inside` -> the next `div` is yours:

```
results = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'row-listing  page-break-inside')]/div")
```

After that you can loop through the results.

```
for ele in results:
      ele.click()
      ...
```

**Example - No `.click()` just `print()`**

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')

html_content = """
<div class="row-listing  page-break-inside  ">
        <div data-ihref="/mercedes-sattelzugmaschine-standard-actros/4x2-euro-6-hydraulikanlage-niedersachsen/ts-vi5576343/gebrauchte.html" data-follow="true" title="Mercedes Sattelzugmaschine" class="display-block decoration-none">...</div>
</div>          
          
<div class="row-listing  page-break-inside  ">
        <div data-ihref="/daf-sattelzugmaschine-standard-cf-440/4x2-euro-6-niedersachsen/ts-vi5577630/gebrauchte.html" data-follow="true" title="DAF Sattelzugmaschine" class="display-block decoration-none">...</div>
</div>  

<div class="row-listing  page-break-inside  ">
        <div data-ihref="/man-sattelzugmaschine-standard-tgx/4x2-euro-6-hessen/ts-vi5575368/gebrauchte.html" data-follow="true" title="MAN Sattelzugmaschine" class="display-block decoration-none">...</div>
</div>  
"""
driver.get("data:text/html;charset=utf-8,{html_content}".format(html_content=html_content))
results = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'row-listing  page-break-inside')]/div")

for ele in results:
  x=ele.get_attribute('data-ihref')
  print(x)
driver.close()
```

**Output**

```
/mercedes-sattelzugmaschine-standard-actros/4x2-euro-6-hydraulikanlage-niedersachsen/ts-vi5576343/gebrauchte.html
/daf-sattelzugmaschine-standard-cf-440/4x2-euro-6-niedersachsen/ts-vi5577630/gebrauchte.html
/man-sattelzugmaschine-standard-tgx/4x2-euro-6-hessen/ts-vi5575368/gebrauchte.html
```